# Powering a Raspberry Pi using 15A supply

Tags: voltage, raspberry-pi, amperage

I'm trying to power a Raspberry Pi off a 5V, 15A power supply. Measured with a multimeter, the voltage is actually a little more than 5 - ~5.25V. I've never powered a Pi with anything more than 2A, so will this be a problem long term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your supply will only supply the current your load (raspberry pi) actually requires. The Amperage rating is the maximum current your supply can supply.